# Break out of loop/continue next from AlertDialog OnClick

Tags: android, loops, android-alertdialog, break

I'm working on an app that requires me to loop thru objects then on certain conditions, need to ask the user if he/she wants to continue or stop.

So I have coded something like.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i == 5) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
      .setTitle("WARNING")
      .setMessage("Do you want to continue?")
      .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
      .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                              break; // -> Not working
                            }
       })
      .setCancelable(false)
      .create()
      .show();
  }
}
```

However, the above code shows an error on the "break;" line saying "Break outside or switch loop".

I also tried using a label and used "break LABEL;" but I get an error "Undefined label: LABEL".

Can anyone help.

Thanks.

Ank

I will be accepting Haresh answer as it did answer my question. However, as pointed out by Pedro Oliveira, it does not block the loop from finishing which is what I was after. Will need to find another approach.

Comment: Keep in mind that this code will create 5 AlertDialogs and **it will not** wait until you click OK or Cancel on the first one.

Comment: @PedroOliveira seems you are right. I tried Haresh Chhelana suggestion but the loop kept on going before showing the Alert Dialog. Now I have to think of another approach for my requirement. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Make one flag at class level and change this flag value in cancle button and try to stop loop base on flag in loop.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean isStop;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i == 5) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("WARNING")
                        .setMessage("Do you want to continue?")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                isStop = true;
                            }
                        })
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .create()
                        .show();
            }
            if (isStop) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this work when the dialogs are not modal i.e. blocking?

Answer (score 0):

Set a boolean flag for this like:

```
boolean keepGoing= true;//u mad bro?

while(i < 10 && continue){
// your loop


if(i == 5){
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
      .setTitle("WARNING")
      .setMessage("Do you want to continue?")
      .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
      .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                              keepGoing=false//
                            }
       })
      .setCancelable(false)
      .create()
      .show();
}
i++;
}
```

Comment: dialogs are not blocking and `continue` is a keyword you cannot use as variable name.

Comment: then use another name for flag and if you use a flag it will effect while statement.

Comment: I got it now. yes dialog does not pause the loop